# Setting up imports correctly: `from x import y` works while `import x.y` does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I am having trouble setting up the import logic for a module. The structure is this:

```
fishy
├── fishy
│   ├── incl
│   │   ├── fish
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── salmon
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── salmon.py
│   │   ├── fish_farm.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└─── setup.py
```

I want to pass certain classes / modules up to be available for import from a higher node in the structure. So I set up all `__init__.py` files like this:

```
fishy/__init__.py
    from .fishy import *

fishy/fishy/__init__.py
    from .incl.fish import Salmon

    from .incl import fish

fishy/fishy/incl/__init__.py
    from .fish import Salmon
    from . import fish

fishy/fishy/incl/fish/__init__.py
    from .salmon import Salmon

fishy/fishy/incl/fish/salmon/__init__.py
    from .salmon import Salmon
```

This however works only partially. I can import the module fine and it also contains the correct submodules / classes:

```
In [1]: import fishy

In [2]: dir(fishy)
Out[2]: 
['Salmon',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'fish',
 'incl']
```

The types also are correct:

```
In [3]: type(fishy)
Out[3]: module

In [4]: type(fishy.fish)
Out[4]: module

In [5]: type(fishy.fish.Salmon)
Out[5]: type
```

I also can import transitively with one syntax:

```
In [6]: from fishy import fish
```

But the other syntax gives me an error, and I cannot figure out why

```
In [7]: import fishy.fish
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-efdcfdf1b06a> in <module>
----> 1 import fishy.fish

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fishy.fish'
```

Why can I do `from fishy import fish` but not `import fishy.fish`? I am very puzzled and been trying to fix this for hours now. Can you enlighten me please? :D Thanks!

Comment: regardless of the answer, I would tell you not to use `import fishy.fish` and instead use the `from fishy import fish` syntax

Comment: ok, kind of very much besides the point, but still... why?

Comment: Sort of general consensus, you're not forced to do it but it's usually better. If you do `import fishy.fish` you can only use the `fish` module from `fishy` and nothing else, yet you still have to use it like `fishy.fish`. Instead, you should either `import fishy` and then use `fishy.fish`, or `from fishy import fish` and use `fish` directly. One of the only reasons to use `import x.y` is because it shadows another name. For example, if you had a module `os` in your personal `mymodule`, you shouldn't do `from mymodule import os` because you'd be shadowing the builtin `os` module.